# Uiwebview refreshes after zoom and pinch

Tags: uiwebview, refresh, zooming, pinch

I have a uiwebview in my App. So far everything works fine, but when i zoom in or out for example the uiwebview refreshes the loaded page and then scrolls and zooms to the new page location and size. So the zooming works good, but I don't want the user to see the refresh and repositioning of the website.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you might have coded your zoom in an odd way.  You could try deleting all your zoom code, and in the same method where you have your webView loadRequest, type:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That wouldn't remove the problem described in the question. When a user zooms in, and the page is refreshed, there will be a flicker which is unpleasant to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh your page dynamically, instead of refreshing it through the webview. You can accomplish this by using AJAX or retrieving the content in Objective C and injecting it using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.